# Express js and EJS weird behaviour on render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron, ejs

I'm making my app using electron as main framework, express.js as middleware and ejs as rendering engine.
i've several calls on express and everything works fine, except for one, which display correct result if i call it from browser like http://localhost:3000/messages/123/1 (123 is the id, and 1 is the channel).
The browser displays all the results (from a sqlite query) correctly in regular browser, but doesn't display anything in electron app.
this is the code

```
   //restapi is an instance of express.js
   restapi.get("/messaggi/:id/:canale", (req, res) => {
//maindb is a working instance of sqlite database
//q is a working query like "SELECT * FROM MESSAGES"
    maindb.all(q,function (err,allrows) {
    console.log("MESSAGES ",allrows);
   res.json({
     data: allrows,
     path: app.getPath('documents'),
     whut:"ID: "+id+" CANALE:"+canale+" ERR: "+err+" L:"+allrows.length
   });

  })


})
```

i've been trying with res.render using an EJS file, and as above, a JSON rendering.
in my log, i can see the result of the query, also in a web browser (i'm using chrome), and i can see and print all the other vars that i'm sending, like "path" or "whut" (used only for testing)

what am i doing wrong?!

Comment: Presume `messaggi` is a typo? As your browser request seems to suggest the URL is `/messages`. Or have you mistakenly added the route as italian when it should be english?

Comment: no, it took the 'id' var with a space at the end (id was calculated from another field) so in my query i was writing something like WHERE id='123(space)' ad obviouslly it returns empty...
so dumb :(

Comment: no probs, if your building dynamic queries make sure your not leaving yourself open to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: it's on a closed system (it an internal app for my business) so security issues are under control :D